# Showing $\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom n k \frac{(-1)^k}{(n+k)(n+k+1)} = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom {n+1} k \frac{ (-1)^k}{n+k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, summation, binomial-coefficients, beta-function

The background context is this old MSE question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1539307/how-to-evaluate-int-01xn-11-xn1dx). Essentially I was trying to write up a proper response for the question, but I'm stuck on one part myself. One goal for the question is to prove the following equality:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom n k \frac{(-1)^k}{(n+k)(n+k+1)} = \int_0^1x^{n-1}(1-x)^{n+1}dx$$

(At least, based on the assumption the OP's notation is that $C_r := \binom n r$ where $n$ is understood to be fixed. Seems to work right when calculating both via Wolfram.) Per a suggestion in the comments, it seems a good route route to go would be expanding $(1-x)^{n+1}$ via the binomial theorem and integrating termwise, and hopefully the expression for the sum "pops out," as it were.

Doing so, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1x^{n-1}(1-x)^{n+1}dx &= \int_0^1 x^{n-1} \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom {n+1} k (-1)^k x^{k}dx \\
&= \int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom {n+1} k (-1)^k x^{n+k-1}dx \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom {n+1} k (-1)^k \int_0^1 x^{n+k-1}dx \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \left. \binom {n+1} k \frac{ (-1)^k}{n+k} x^{n+k} \right|_{x=0}^1\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom {n+1} k \frac{ (-1)^k}{n+k}
\end{align}$$

So far so good, but with one issue. What remains, seemingly, is to show

$$\binom n k \frac{1}{n+k+1} = \binom{n+1}k \tag 1$$

However, these two quantities are unequal. For instance, $n=10,k=5$ give us $63/4 = 462$, pure nonsense. So this suggests something in my work along the way is wrong ... but what? I've checked and double-checked a lot, and I'm not sure where I went wrong in this derivation, or how to move forward. Perhaps I'm overlooking something obvious, but does anyone have any ideas?

One hypothesis was that the original inequality I seek to prove is false, but it seems not. For instance, take $n=15$. Then the [sum](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k%3D0+to+16+of+C%2815%2Ck%29+*+%28-1%29%5Ek+*+1%2F%28%2815%2Bk%29%2815%2Bk%2B1%29%29) and [integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+0+to+1+of+x%5E14+%281-x%29%5E16+dx) evaluate to about $2.2182 \times 10^{-10}$ per WolframAlpha, and I tried a few other $n$ besides that. So the issue almost certainly lies in my derivation. But [my sum](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k%3D0+to+16+of+C%2816%2Ck%29+%28-1%29%5Ek+%2F+%2815%2Bk%29) also evaluates to this for the prescribed value of $n=15$... which suggests another possible problem.

Another possibility is that I'm oversimplifying the matter by assuming

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom n k \frac{(-1)^k}{(n+k)(n+k+1)} = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom {n+1} k \frac{ (-1)^k}{n+k}$$

would imply corresponding terms are equal (which was my motivation for the earlier equality $(1)$ which is a clear dead-end). For clarity, that means I assumed $\sum a_n = \sum b_n \implies a_n = b_n$. While that'd obviously make everyone's life easier, it's definitely not necessarily true. Which, if it's not in this case, I'm not sure where to go, and would like any potential nudges forward on the matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n}k\frac{(-1)^k}{(n+k)(n+k+1)}&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n}k\left(\frac{(-1)^k}{n+k}-\frac{(-1)^k}{n+k+1}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n}k\frac{(-1)^k}{n+k}-\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n}k\frac{(-1)^k}{n+k+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n}k\frac{(-1)^k}{n+k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n}k\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{n+k+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n}k\frac{(-1)^k}{n+k}+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{n}{k-1}\frac{(-1)^k}{n+k}\\
&=\frac1n+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\left(\binom{n}k+\binom{n}{k-1}\right)\frac{(-1)^k}{n+k}\\
&=\frac1n+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}k\frac{(-1)^k}{n+k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}k\frac{(-1)^k}{n+k}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Minor question, how is the first equality justified? I can see the rest of the process, and know a partial fraction decomposition is involved, but I'm having trouble justifying that one in full

Comment: Oh I see now, it was a typo. Sorry for the silly question, this problem has had my brain fried all night!

Comment: @EeveeTrainer: There was a typo on the lefthand side, which I've now fixed; the actual manipulation is just partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer: I'm glad that you asked: it led me to spot the typo!